# JavaMail equivalent in C# to read/parse mail?

Tags: c#, .net

[JavaMail, for those who dont know.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)

Anyway, is there an equivalent to this in C#/.Net? I need to access my Gmail account for testing purposes, but using a regular automation tool would be too hard.

I need to be able to read and parse GMail. Similar to what this article is doing in Java: http://seleniumsoftwaretesting.blogspot.com/2011/08/verify-email-confirmation-using.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to download / parse messages (rather than just send them, which is provided in `System.Net.Mail` as others have said) you can look at this free option:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx

There are paid options as well, such as Aspose.Network for .NET:

http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.network-for-.net/default.aspx

Comment: Even though I wont up using a different product, this post helped point me into the right direction. Ultimately I needed something to download and parse. It was my fault for not specifying that in the OP

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [`System.Net.Mail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

This is available.  I didn't see where you listed what features of JavaMail you needed, but this is one mail option.

Answer (score 0):

The nuget package AE.Net.Mail is an analog or equivalent to JavaMail for reading/parsing email in the RFC 2822 format. I used it with the Gmail API to get the "Raw" property that the Gmail API wants. See the code here for a code sample:
[Creating a Message for Gmail API in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728793/creating-a-message-for-gmail-api-in-c-sharp/26599752#26599752)

The library's project:
https://github.com/andyedinborough/aenetmail