# Sending Email with Gmail API, Encoding Greek characters in body

Tags: c#, character-encoding, gmail-api

I'm updating an application for sending emails to use the GMAIL API instead of SMTP.

I am facing a problem with encoding of the email. The subject is shown as it should, but the body is not shown properly. *[below is a screenshot of the recieved email]*

[image: screenshot-of-the-recieved-email]

the code i am using to send the email:

```
public bool SendMailGmailAPI(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage, GmailService service)
    {
        bool isEverythingOK = false;
        try
        {
            var mimeMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(mailMessage);

            string mm = mimeMessage.ToString();
            var gmailMessage = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message
            {
                Raw = Encode(mm)
            };

            UsersResource.MessagesResource.SendRequest request = service.Users.Messages.Send(gmailMessage, mailMessage.From.Address);
            request.Execute();
            isEverythingOK = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorMessage = e.Message;
            isEverythingOK = false;
        }
        return isEverythingOK;
    }


public static string Encode(string text)
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

          return  System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
                .Replace('+', '-')
                .Replace('/', '_')
                .Replace("=", "");
        }
```

mailMessage is generated from this:

```
      public MailMessage CreateEmailMessage(string mailto="")
        {
            EmailMessageToSend = new MailMessage();
            //setting from, to, cc, bcc, replyto

            //make body
            EmailMessageToSend.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            //EmailMessageToSend.HeadersEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            EmailMessageToSend.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            EmailMessageToSend.IsBodyHtml = true;

            EmailMessageToSend.Body = Body + "<hr>";
            EmailMessageToSend.Body += DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
            EmailMessageToSend.Body += "<br /><br />ΔΗΛΩΣΗ ΕΜΠΙΣΤΕΥΤΙΚΟΤΗΤΑΣ / ΑΠΟΠΟΙΗΣΗ ΕΥΘΥΝΗΣ <br /> Αυτό το μήνυμα περιέχει εμπιστευτικές και απόρρητες πληροφορίες και η χρήση τους επιτρέπεται μόνον από τον αναφερόμενο παραλήπτη. Σε περίπτωση που περιέλθει σε σας από λάθος, παρακαλούμε να το διαγράψετε άμεσα από το σύστημά σας ή να το καταστρέψετε και να ειδοποιήσετε τον αποστολέα.  <br /><br />" +" CONFIDENTIALITY WARNING / DISCLAIMER <br /> The information in this email is confidential and is intended solely for the addressee(s). If you have received this transmission in error, and you are not an intended recipient, be aware that any disclosure, copying, distribution or use of this transmission or its contents is prohibited.";

            var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(EmailMessageToSend.Body, null, "text/html");
            EmailMessageToSend.Subject = Subject+" - Mail v2.0";

            return EmailMessageToSend;
        }
```

on mimeMessage.ToString() i get this result 
[image: visualstudio-textview-mm-variable]

Any suggestions on how to fix the encoding problem?

Comment: Encoding should be using one of the Windows encoding like 1250,1251,1252, 1290 not UTF8.

Comment: Try adding this in the HTML body boundary : content-transfer-encoding : utf8 or content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable for non ascii characters and charset: windows-1253

Comment: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Comment: @jdweng i tried all of these encodings but the email is showing greek characters as ? (question marks)

Comment: @JamesDean how can i add it?  can you give an example?

Comment: What are you using to view email?  You can't use text mode.  You need Rich Text  mode.

Comment: @jdweng I am using gmail in chrome to see the email.

Comment: Are you in standard view or html view ? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/15049?hl=en

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it's still relevant, however.
Ran into the same problem recently and spent quite frustrating hours in attempts to find solution. And it appeared to be pretty simple - don't use MimeMessage.ToString() method as it's marked as 'unreliable' by the authors. Use WriteTo(Stream stream) instead.

Something like this:

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(msg);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    mimeMessage.WriteTo(ms);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.GetBuffer())
        .TrimEnd('=')
        .Replace('+', '-')
        .Replace('/', '_');
}
```